# Write a SQL query where one of the columns is a subset of the other?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table like this:

```
Date    | Action | Ad_ID | Device_ID
--------+--------+-------+-----------
5/13/19 | click  |  342  | 22289
5/14/19 | view   |  342  | 22289
```

I need to write a query to get the number of users that clicked on an at least one ad in a given day, AND the number of users from the first set that view an ad the next day.

How would I go about this? I'm very new to SQL and trying to use it in a work sense :)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  How do you know if a user viewed or clicked on an ad?

Comment: edited with more info @GordonLinoff

Comment: Assuming that any click on any ad by any user will add a new row:

An MSSQL query for number of users that clicked on an at least one ad in a given day might look like:
`select count(distinct Device_ID) from my_table where Date = Convert(DATE, GetDate())`

Comment: but how do I get the number of users from that set who clicked the following day? @paulsm4

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a CTE and a self-`LEFT JOIN`, with aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT date, device_id, action FROM mytable t)
SELECT 
    c.date,
    COUNT(c.device_id) clicked,
    COUNT(v.device_id) viewed_the_next_day
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN cte v 
    ON  v.date = c.date + INTERVAL '1 day'
    AND v.device_id = c.device_id 
    AND v.action = 'view'
WHERE x.action = 'click'
GROUP BY c.date
```

The CTE generates a list of unique `date/device_id/action` tuples (this is step might not be necessary, depending on your real data structure). Then, the `LEFT JOIN` puts in relation users that clicked on one day with those who viewed the next day.

Comment: thank you - is there any way to do this without CTEs?

Comment: Well,  first off, as mentionned in my answer: if tuples `date/device_id/action` are unique in your table then you don't need a (you can just remove the CTE declaration and replace `cte` with `mytable` in the query).

Comment: And second: why would you want to avoid CTE? Without it, you would need to repeat the `SELECT DISTINCT ...` twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve something like this?

```
select t1.*, t2.date, t2.action 
from tableA t1
left join tableA t2 
     on t1.date + INTERVAL '1 day' = t2.date 
     and t2.action = 'view'
     and t2.Device_ID= t1.Device_ID
     and t2.Ad_ID= t1.Ad_ID
```